# react dynamically add children to jsx/component

Tags: reactjs

**Situation**

I'm attempting to render a component based on template jsx pieces. Reason being because I have a few of these situations in my app but with subtle customizations and I'd rather leave the business logic for the customizations in the respective component, not the factory.

**Example**

Parent Template

```
<div></div>
```

Child Template

```
<p></p>
```

In the render function I want to add n child components to the parent. So if n=4 then I would expect output like

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I tried using `parentTemplate.children.push` with no avail because the group template is still JSX at this point and not yet a rendered component. How can I accomplish this task using jsx + react ?

**Extra**

Here is what my actual code looks like so far

```
render() {

    let groupTemplate = <ListGroup></ListGroup>

    let itemTemplate = (item) => {
        return <ListGroup.Item>{item.name}</ListGroup.Item>;
    }
    if (this.props.itemTemplate) itemTemplate = this.props.itemTemplate;

    let itemsJsx;
    this.props.navArray.forEach((item) => {
        groupTemplate.children.push(itemTemplate(item))
    });

    return (
        [groupTemplate]  
    );
}
```

From the parent:

```
const groupTemplate = <ListGroup className='custom-container-classes'></ListGroup>
const itemTemplate = <ListGroup.Item className='customized-classes'></ListGroup.Item>
<NavigationFactory groupTemplate={groupTemplate} itemTemplate={itemTemplate}>
</NavigationFactory>
```

Comment: In your question you have `Example Parent Template Child Template` seems like missing piece you intended to add to your question?

Comment: @Rikin good catch. It was in there but it was hidden because there needed to be an empty line before the example code.

Comment: @Rikin your answer was the closest to a working solution yet. I'm tinkering with it to see if I can make it work.

Comment: @Rikin I got it to work based on your code. If you put your answer back I'll make the minor edits to it.

Comment: answer back up on the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear on your question but I have attempted to figure out based on your code on what you are trying to do, see if it helps, else I'll delete my answer.

The mechanism of below code working is that it takes in groupTemplate which in your case you'll be passing in as a prop which then takes children within it and returns them composed all together. There's default children group template which you can use if no related prop is passed and you have a mapper function within the render which determines which template to use and renders `n` number of times based on `navArray` length.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // setup default templates

    if (!this.props.navButtonContainerTemplate) {
        this.prop.navButtonContainerTemplate = (items) => {
            return <ListGroup>{items}</ListGroup>
        }
    }

    if (!this.props.navButtonTemplate) {
        this.props.navButtonTemplate = (item) => {
            return (
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    {item.name}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            )
        }
    }
}

render() {

    const itemsJsx = this.props.navArray.map(obj => {
        const itemJsx = this.props.navButtonTemplate(obj)
        return itemJsx;
    });

    return this.props.navButtonContainerTemplate(itemsJsx);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use render props, which is the best way to achieve something like that:

The parent:

```
<NavigationFactory 
     itemTemplate={itemTemplate}
     render={children => <ListGroup className='custom-container-classes'>
          {children}
     </ListGroup>}
 />
```

The Child:

```
render() {
     this.props.render(this.props.navArray.map(item => <ListGroup.Item key={item.id}>
       {item.name}
  </ListGroup.Item>))
}
```

This will let you define the container on your calling function and enables you to create the chidlren as you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My `ListGroup` is JSX. It needs to stay this way as the jsx will ultimately be passed in as a prop - that's the core of why I'm stuck on this. Is it possible to pre-render the jsx and then add children via a map / loop?

Comment: But the map will create a jsx array like this: [<Item>...</Item>, <Item>...</Item>,...]. What do you need exactly.

Comment: This is correct just don't forget to add a key when mapping

Comment: @Domino987 in your example the `ListGroup` is static inside the render function. Unfortunately I don't have that luxury because the groupTemplate will be passed in as JSX from the parent via props. So I have to figure out some way of injecting the mapped jsx inside of the groupTemplate's JSX. I could do it with string manipulation but I'm sure there is a 'more correct' way with react.

Comment: So you are saying that groupTemplate  is actually a prop, which you have to append children to? Correct? Can you show us, how you call the component?

Comment: @Domino987 Yes you've got the idea. I added a sample of what the parent component would look like.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I updated my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: Rikin answered the question but then he deleted his answer. It wasn't perfect but I tweaked it to get it to work. I saved the code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jbhwze5/) if you want to check it out. I'm waiting to see if he un-delete's his answer tomorrow so I can mark it. Otherwise it's free game.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the contents as regular children to the `ListGroup` via standard JSX nesting:

```
render() {
    let itemTemplate = (item) => {
        return <ListGroup.Item>{item.name}</ListGroup.Item>;
    }
    if (this.props.itemTemplate) itemTemplate = this.props.itemTemplate;

    return (
        <ListGroup>
            {this.props.navArray.map(item => (
                itemTemplate(item)
            ))}
        </ListGroup>
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still has static code in the return so it won't work for the reason I need it.